# ASP.NET MVC Calling Controller Method DevExpress

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I'm trying to call a method on the controller but it gives me a null error. I was trying to do the getKeyValue on the code but it won't work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for any help.

Controller code

```
public  ActionResult EditRecord(int id)
{
    int x = id;

    return PartialView("~/Views/FileMaintenance/Principal/EditPrincipal.cshtml", PrincipalInfo);
}
```

DevExpress GridView code

```
settings.Columns.Add(column =>
        {
            column.FieldName = "Unbound";
            column.Caption = "Action";
            column.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Object;
            column.EditFormSettings.Visible = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;
            column.ReadOnly = false;

            column.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.ButtonEdit;
            column.SetDataItemTemplateContent((c) =>
            {

                Html.DevExpress().Button(b =>
                {
                    b.Name = "btnVE" + c.KeyValue;
                    b.Text = "V/E";
                    b.UseSubmitBehavior = false; // prevent default submit action
                    b.EnableClientSideAPI = true; // add this line if not sure
                    b.ClientSideEvents.Click = string.Format("function(s, e) {{ window.location = '{0}?key={1}'; }}",
                            DevExpressHelper.GetUrl(new { Controller = "ViewPrincipal", Action = "EditRecord" }),
                            c.KeyValue.ToString());
                }).GetHtml();
            });
        });
```

Error

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult EditRecord(Int32)' in 'WMS_Web.Controllers.FileMaintenance.ViewPrincipalController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't supply the parameter `id` in the `DevExpressHelper.GetUrl` method. You need to set it. In the example below I placed a value of 1. I do not understand why you are placing a "key" in the query string when the required is "id". Changing "key" to "id" should also solve your problem.

```
settings.Columns.Add(column =>     
{
        column.FieldName = "Unbound";
        column.Caption = "Action";
        column.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Object;
        column.EditFormSettings.Visible = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;
        column.ReadOnly = false;

        column.ColumnType = MVCxGridViewColumnType.ButtonEdit;
        column.SetDataItemTemplateContent((c) =>
        {

            Html.DevExpress().Button(b =>
            {
                b.Name = "btnVE" + c.KeyValue;
                b.Text = "V/E";
                b.UseSubmitBehavior = false; // prevent default submit action
                b.EnableClientSideAPI = true; // add this line if not sure
                b.ClientSideEvents.Click = string.Format("function(s, e) {{ window.location = '{0}'; }}",
                        DevExpressHelper.GetUrl(new { Controller = "ViewPrincipal", Action = "EditRecord", id = c.KeyValue.ToString() }));
            }).GetHtml();
        });
    });
```

Comment: oohh... i see... i made it like this 
    b.ClientSideEvents.Click = string.Format("function(s, e) {{ window.location = '{0}?key={1}'; }}",
                            DevExpressHelper.GetUrl(new { Controller = "ViewPrincipal", Action = "EditRecord",id=c.KeyValue.ToString() }),
                            c.KeyValue.ToString());

Comment: If you want to follow your original approach, changing `window.location = '{0}?key={1}';` to `window.location = '{0}?id={1}';` should also work for you.